# Where is block in memory Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, stack, block

```
int b = 100;
NSLog(@"b in stack:%p", &b);

NSString *str1 = @"Hello World";
NSLog(@"&str1 in stack:%p", &str1);

NSLog(@"block:%p", ^(){});

id block = ^(){};
NSLog(@"block in heap: %p", block);
```

then, the log is here:

```
b in stack:0x7fff5fbff75c
&str1 in stack:0x7fff5fbff750
block:0x100001170
block in heap: 0x1000011b0
```

I looked up lots of blogs, many say `NSLog(@"block:%p", ^(){});`'s block in stack, but why it's different from the first two according to the address logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first two you are printing the address of the local variable, which is in the stack. In the last two the block is allocated in the heap and you are printing its address. Try `NSLog(@"block in heap: %p", &block);` and you'll see it prints the address where the `block` variable is stored, instead its content. In the third case you can't do it since you are creating a temporal variable directly on the argument.

Comment: The last two cases show that block was created in stack and copied to heap when passed to a variable, but in my prints, the third's address is really far away from the first and second, so where is the third block in, stack or heap or somewhere? Is there any mistake with my comprehension？

Comment: [This image](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/images/Chapter3/3_01_Process_Memory.jpg) may help to understand the difference: the stack and the heap are traditionally in opposite ends of the memory address space, that's why you see such distance between them.

Comment: On the other hand, in the first two blocks you are printing out the address where the variable resides, not its content, while in the third and fourth cases you are printing the content of the variable (an object, i.e., a pointer). As I mentioned, if you `NSLog(@"block in heap: %p", &block)` as a fifth case, then you'll see that `block` is in the stack as 1) and 2), but its content (the actual object) is in the heap. It also applies to any `[NSObject alloc]`, `malloc`, etc.

Comment: BTW, [this video](https://youtu.be/_8-ht2AKyH4?t=10m50s) may explain graphically and better than me the stack/heap situation with pointers.

Comment: you mean that the third one is also in heap, just like the forth.

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that the forth is explicitly stored in a variable, while the third is created directly in the function call (and copied to a temporal variable).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the memory address of the block, use

`@"%@"` than `@"%p"`

I don't know what you doubt exactly, but I think my answer can help you.

1. Block is basically allocated on the stack, under the condition below:

   - Block captures at least one variable.
   - If you don't assign the block to variable.
2. Block is going to be allocated on the heap when:

   - Block captures at least one variable.
   - If you assign the block to any variables(Member variable or local variable).
3. Block is going to be allocated on the static area when:

   - Block captures nothing.

Cheers!